# On numbers of the form $\pm x^2\pm N_k$, with $x\geq 1$ integer and $N_k$ denoting primorials

Tags: asymptotics, diophantine-equations, analytic-number-theory, square-numbers, primorial

In this post we consider **positive** integers $a$ of the form $$\pm x^2\pm N_k\tag{1}$$ with $x\geq 1$ integer and for integers $k\geq 1$ denoting  $$N_k=\prod_{j=1}^k p_j$$ as the primorial of order $k$, thus here $p_j$ denotes the $j$th prime number.

**Definitions.** We denote this set of integers as $$\mathcal{A}=\{\text{positive integers }a=\pm x^2\pm N_k\text{ s.t. }x\geq 1 \text{ is integer and }N_k\text{ is a primorial for some }k\}.$$
For a fixed real $T>0$ we denote $\mathcal{A}(T)$ the set $$\mathcal{A}(T)=\mathcal{A}\cap[1,T],$$ and the counting function of these numbers $a$ in the segment $[1,T]$ as $\#\mathcal{A}(T)$.

> **Question.**
>
> Can you calculate a sharp upper bound on the counting function $\#\mathcal{A}(T)$?
>
> Can you prove that $$\sum_{a\in \mathcal{A}}\frac{1}{a}$$
>   is divergent?
>
> **Many thanks.**

I did few experiments to state previous conjectures. The sequence of integers with such representation starts as $1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11,14,15,18,19,\ldots$

To ask my questions I was inspired in similar statements that are in the literature Florian Luca and Alain Togbé, *On numbers of the form* $\pm x^2\pm y!$, from  *Diophantine Equations*, Editor: N. Saradha, Narosa Publishing House, (2008).

I don't know if my sequence $(1)$ and the questions are in the literature, if it is in the literature answer the question as a reference request, and I try to find and read those propositions solving the Question.

Comment: The product of the primes upto $p$ is usually denoted with "#p"

Comment: Many thanks @Peter for such notation, of course any user can to use it in his/her answer.

Comment: It is quite unclear whether the set is dense enough to give a divergent series. Did you determine larger such numbers, for example in the range $[10^5,10^6]$ ?

Comment: I didn't it. My reasoning was/is very poor due that I've calculated only the first few terms of the sequence (and I know that due that there are a lot of primes upto $100$, my reasoning should be maybe wrong) @Peter Feel free if you want to illustratre how grows the cardinality $\#\mathcal{A}(T)$, or the size of the sequence  $\sum_{a\in \mathcal{A}(T_l)}\frac{1}{a}$ for enough large $T_l>0$